# What is the default operator in Rules module conditions?

Tags: rules

I have an issue on production site that I cannot reproduce.

The Rule below should trigger an email if the new content is published. But emails are being send even if content is not published.

```
{ "rules_content_new" : {
  "LABEL" : "Notify new content",
  "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
  "OWNER" : "rules",
  "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
  "ON" : { "node_insert--article" : { "bundle" : "article" } },
  "IF" : [
  { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:status" ], "value" : "1" } },
  { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:field-custom" ], "value" : "13" } }
  ],
  "DO" : [
  { "mail" : {
  "to" : "test@mail.com",
  "bcc" : "[site:full-mailing-list]",
  "subject" : "[node:title]",
  "message" : "new content available",
  "from" : "test@from.com",
  "language" : [ "" ]
  }
  }
  ]
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

From official [Rules documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1300034):

> By default, Rules assumes AND operators between conditions (if no OR
>   group is explicitly used).

Syntactically there is nothing wrong with your rule.

A little tip for troubleshooting this rule *(because obviously that rule does not give you any error messages)* - add action "Show a message on the site" and output values from your conditions in that message. If the values shown are correct but the rule still malfunctions - try deleting it and then recreate it.

Also, you can try using Rules condition "Content is published" instead of checking the value of node:status. It is basically the same thing, but maybe in your situation will give a different result.